# How to write SQL pivot without aggregation

Tags: sql, sql-server

can you please help in writing SQL statement for below output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()` & do aggregation :

```
select name, 
       max(case when seq = 1 then colors end) as color1,
       max(case when seq = 2 then colors end) as color2
from(select t.*, row_number() over (partition by name order by colors) as seq
     from table t
    ) t
group by name;
```

**EDIT** : If you don't want to do aggergation then you can use `CTE` :

```
with cte as (
     select t.*, row_number() over (partition by t.name order by t.color) as seq
     from table t
)
select distinct c.name, c1.color as color1, c2.color as color2
from cte c inner join
     cte c1
     on c1.name = c.name and c1.seq = 1 inner join
     cte c2
     on c2.name = c.name and c2.seq = 2;
```

Comment: can you explain why you use this row_number(), i am geting result with out this aswell.. can you please help understand it.

Comment: @user11894930. . . If you don't use `row_number` then you need to specify the color names that might be tough. So, by using `rownumber` we can easily get color name.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this.

```
DECLARE @TableA TABLE (Name VARCHAR(10), Colors VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO @TableA 
VALUES
('Betty', 'Pink'),
('Betty', 'Blue'),
('Jug', 'Purple'),
('Jug', 'White')

SELECT Name, [1] AS Color1, [2] AS Color2 FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Name) AS RN 
    FROM @TableA 
) SRC PIVOT (MAX(Colors) FOR RN IN ([1],[2]) ) PVT
```

Result:

```
Name       Color1     Color2
---------- ---------- ----------
Betty      Pink       Blue
Jug        Purple     White
```

Comment: Thank you Serkan Arslan

Answer (score 0):

SQL tables have no ordering.  So, there is no way (other than explicit logic) to put the columns in a particular order.

So, I would recommend simply using aggregation:

```
select name, min(color) as color1, max(color) as color2
from tablea
group by name;
```

This does not return the columns in the same order as you have them.  However, nothing in the *data* specifies that ordering, so I don't understand how you are defining it.